# AngularJS: Show Textfield depending on Select Option

Tags: angularjs

I have a Dropdown with Differnt Options (Numbers). If a number was selected, an amount of textfields should be shown depending on the number that was selected before.

Example:

User selects number = 2
There should be two time a textfield called "name"

```
                <select name="singleSelect" id="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect">
                    <option value="0">---Please select---</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option> 
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select><br>





     <div ng-repeat="t in vm.getTimes({{data.singleSelect}}) track by $index">
     {{$index}} 
    <input ng-model="text1" /> <!-- this textfield should be repeated--></div>
```

Function getTimes in the controller:

```
vm.getTimes = function (n) {
        return new Array(n);
    };
```

I can´t pass `vm.getTimes` the selected option - why not?

If I write an INT for `{{data.singleSelect}}` in the function `getTimes`, it works.

Comment: remove {{ }} from data.singleSelect

Comment: doesn´t work, the textfield is only shown once, regardless of the number selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getTimes` function should be like this.

```
getTimes = function (n) {
            if(n){
                  return new Array(parseInt(n));  
            }else{
                  return 0;
            } 
        }
```

> Why it is not working?

The parameter you passing create array of length initialised  using 
 with the same value.

Because `n` is string.
You need to parse it to Integer.

Check [`JavaScript#Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Here is the working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cdwY1EzKRAL0qlwC9eyO?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You ve a fixed number of options so you can use limitTo

```js
var app = angular.module("app", [])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <select name="singleSelect" id="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect">
    <option value="0">---Please select---</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <br>

  <div ng-repeat="t in [1,2] | limitTo:data.singleSelect track by $index">
    {{$index}}
    <input ng-model="text1" />
    <!-- this textfield should be repeated-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a new array based on the input (that you assume is a number), but you never ensure that this will indeed be one.

For example:

`t in getNumber(data.singleSelect * 1) track by $index` would solve it, or

```
$scope.getNumber = function (num) {
  return new Array(parseInt(num));
}
```

would also make your loop function properly.

What you're trying to do:

```
> new Array("2")
< ["2"]
```

What you should do:

```
> new Array(2)
< [undefined × 2] 
//don't worry about undefined for now, but this array has 0 and 1 elements.
```

Here's an updated fiddle with your sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/rPhFnmmKNvHtSirGCYHG?p=preview